# How do I automate cmd commands to run flask server

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Every time I start working on my Flask project I need to run these commands in cmd:

```
cd myproject
venv\scripts\activate
set FLASK_APP=project
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Is there a way to make a batch file that would execute these commands?

Comment: Google search “docker” and “docker-compose” with flask. I think this is what you need without having to create a virtual env. Here is an example: https://dev.to/alissonzampietro/the-amazing-journey-of-docker-compose-17lj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this could help you.
Open `notepad` and write the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL venv\scripts\activate
set FLASK_APP=project
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Save this as `run.bat` inside your `myproject` directory.

Then, if you still want to interact with the bat file after your execution you can call this new script, in the following way:

```
cmd /k path\to\myproject\run.bat
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. It worked. I would just like to add the command "cmd \k" at the end to keep the cmd window open.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you:

create **init**.py in your app folder (project):

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # configure the app here

    return app
```

then create run.py

```
from project import create_app

app = create_app()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000", debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

then all you have to do is type python run.py an there you go. (make sure you're in virtual environment)

Comment: Thank you your answer is intresting. I didn't think you could go around it that way ;)